# How do I create multiple boxplots whilst also making them proportional using geom_boxplot within ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I understand that varwidth = TRUE within ggplot2's geom_boxplot can be used to create proportional boxplots so that each boxplot also summarises the number of points within a plot. However, I am struggling to maintain proportional boxplot sizes whilst also producing multiple plots?

Using the diamonds df in ggplot2 I am trying to reproduce the below image. 
[image: vertical proportional geom_boxplot]

What I have tried is this:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = carat, y = price)) + geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(group = cut_number(carat, 20), varwidth = TRUE))
```

I tried to use cut_number to achieve the multiple, and var-width for proportionality. I'd also like to have the boxplots show vertically. I have been stumped on this for hours and have looked online but to no avail. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ggplot2 v3.3.0, the orientation of layers are autodetected. In some cases, this detection can be incorrect. You can force the orientation by adding it as an argument to a layer:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = carat, y = price)) + 
  geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(group = cut_number(carat, 20)),
               orientation = "x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Just to embed my understanding further. ggplot 3.30 now automatically able to size plots so that width is proportional to the number of points without "varwidth" being required? 

Furthermore, without the orientation argument, the horizontal view actually had proportionality but this was perhaps hidden in the plots being squished together?

Comment: The grouping makes it such that there are 20 observations per box. The width of the boxplots is approximately `0.9*range(x)` per group. The varwidth argument controls the width by number of observations, so with `cut_number()` being applied, varwidths should all be equal.